# XML forms in joomla3.1

Tags: xml, forms, joomla

Would be possible to create with one form xml multiple forms for multiple views. I would like to avoid to have couple of xml's per view. I already have one created and I would like to  to include somehow other views

```
--models
---forms
----subject.xml
```

**this one holds custom fileds**

```
--models
---fields
----subject.php
```

**the xml**

```
<form>
        <fieldset>

         <field name="faculty" type="subject"
            label="COM_UNIS_FIELDSET_FACULTY"
            description="COM_UNIS_FIELDSET_FACULTY_DESC"
            class="inputbox right"
            size="50"
        />
         <field name="subject" type="text"
            label="COM_UNIS_FIELDSET_SUBJECT_TITLE_LABEL"
            description="COM_UNIS_FIELDSET_SUBJECT_TITLE_DESC"
            class="inputbox right"
            size="30"
               />

        </fieldset>
</form>
```

in subject model I have the following methods which are getForm(), loadFormData(), getTable() which are retrieving datas from table

this one generates form for subject view

and how to generate a form inside subject.xml for faculties view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include other xml forms you can do addFormPath.

Comment: thank you for your feedback! Can you please explain where to add and how to use it, the joomla doc is not really explanatory

Comment: Show what research you have done and what you have tried but hasn't worked.  You might want to start by both grepping and googling addFormPath.